# In Dojo, how can I drawing custom markers at data points?

Tags: charts, dojo, marker, tooltip

I'm using Dojo for drawing my charts. I need to draw an overlay at certain points. Almost like a tooltip that’s always shows.  It can be a stack of values or an icon that display above, below or next to the data-point.

Does anyone know how I can accomplish this?
Does anyone know how I can access the list of screen coordinates for each plotted data-point?

My theory is; if there is no way to draw a persistent and custom tooltip, to draw over the chart and position my custom object in relation to the point coordinate.
Another option would be to draw a custom marker.  (Not like the normal SVG paths.)

Please don’t suggest another charting library. I need to know how to do this in Dojo.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I just want to comment that I'm no longer using Dojo but are using Highcharts instead. So much for NOT suggesting another charting library. I blame my boss :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if you already have found an answer to using custom markers. I am using the SVG path variable for plotting the custom marker.

For eg:

```
var custom_marker = "M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z" // a triangle
var data = [{x: 10, y: 20, marker: custom_marker}, {x: 15, y: 25, marker: custom_marker}] // and so on
```

Feed this data into dojo chart and you can plot the custom marker.